# Do not ask "Run or Display" for certain file extensions

Tags: nautilus, files, extension

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and already stuck on something simple: When trying to open a plain text file with the file extension .txt, it always asks whether i want to run or display the file.

Now, if the file has the ending .txt, I ALWAYS want it to be displayed in gedit. I never want to run it. Is there a way to skip that dialogue? I think the file manager is Nautilus.

To be specific: I don't want to skip the dialogue for all plain text documents! Just for those with the ending ".txt".

Glad if someone could help me, its pretty annoying since I'm editing a lot of text files :-)

Comment: If you right-click>Properties and switch to the Permissions tab (I don't remember the exact name in Nautilus), is the Executable checkbox checked or unchecked? If it's checked, try unchecking it. Also, Linux doesn't need file extensions for text files, and usually doesn't have any.

Comment: @Web-E: I think that it is not an exact duplicate, because the linked answer only gives an answer about _all_ files, not files with certain extensions. It could be possible that Thomas wants to write to *.txt files but also wants run *.sh files. (about .txt: like saiarcot895 said, the extension is not needed, but it could be used to distinguish between e.g. text files and scripts)

Comment: I think the question here is why your `.txt` files would be marked as executable in the first place. Please follow @saiarcot895's advice and check your files' permissions. You might be facing issues with how your filesystem is mounted. Under some circumstances volumes might be mounted with executable permission on all files (mostly happens with NTFS volumes).